# Use PrismJS without syntax highlighting?

Tags: javascript, prismjs

I'm experiencing this issue here: https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/issues/3339 with the PrismJS plugin: https://prismjs.com/.  Larger scripts are freezing mobile devices, and ultimately becoming unresponsive.

So for now I'm not rendering Prism on mobile devices by using the data-manual attribute on the script tag, and the following code:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
    
    // device detection
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
        isMobile = true;
    }
    
    if (!(isMobile)) {
        //only render on desktop devices.  Prism is slow on mobiles, especially with large scripts.
        Prism.highlightAll(false, function () {});
    }    
}
```

By default I use the plugins for 'Toolbar', 'Line Numbers' and 'Copy'.  And I'm wondering, rather than not rendering Prism at all on mobile devices, is there any way I can just render the 'Toolbar' and 'Copy' plugins WITHOUT syntax highlighting (which presumably takes so long) and 'Line Numbers'?

Answer (score 0):

I created a 'solution' myself.  It's a bit of a cheat, but I basically replace all classes that start with language- with the default language-markup class on mobiles only.  The 'markup' syntax highlighting renders much faster than, for example, the powershell syntax.  This way I also get to keep my line numbers, language label and copy functionality on mobile devices.

Note that i do also add 'line-numbers' and 'language-markup' attributes to my body tag, and hence this logic isn't included in the script below.

```
/*Prism config scripts*/

/* PrismJS 1.28.0 */
var _self="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof WorkerGlobalScope&&self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope?self:{},Prism=function(e){var n=/(?:^|\s)lang(?:uage)?-([\w-]+)(?=\s|$)/i,t=0,r={},a={manual:e.Prism&&e.Prism.manual,disableWorkerMessageHandler:e.Prism&&e.Prism.disableWorkerMessageHandler,util:{encode:function e(n){return n instanceof i?new i(n.type,e(n.content),n.alias):Array.isArray(n)?n.map(e):n.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/\u00a0/g," ")},type:function(e){return Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8,-1)},objId:function(e){return e.__id||Object.defineProperty(e,"__id",{value:++t}),e.__id},clone:function e(n,t){var r,i;switch(t=t||{},a.util.type(n)){case"Object":if(i=a.util.objId(n),t[i])return t[i];for(var l in r={},t[i]=r,n)n.hasOwnProperty(l)&&(r[l]=e(n[l],t));return r;case"Array":return i=a.util.objId(n),t[i]?t[i]:(r=[],t[i]=r,n.forEach((function(n,a){r[a]=e(n,t)})),r);default:return n}},getLanguage:function(e){for(;e;){var t=n.exec(e.className);if(t)return t[1].toLowerCase();e=e.parentElement}return"none"},setLanguage:function(e,t){e.className=e.className.replace(RegExp(n,"gi"),""),e.classList.add("language-"+t)},currentScript:function(){if("undefined"==typeof document)return null;if("currentScript"in document)return document.currentScript;try{throw new Error}catch(r){var e=(/at [^(\r\n]*\((.*):[^:]+:[^:]+\)$/i.exec(r.stack)||[])[1];if(e){var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script");for(var t in n)if(n[t].src==e)return n[t]}return null}},isActive:function(e,n,t){for(var r="no-"+n;e;){var a=e.classList;if(a.contains(n))return!0;if(a.contains(r))return!1;e=e.parentElement}return!!t}},languages:{plain:r,plaintext:r,text:r,txt:r,extend:function(e,n){var t=a.util.clone(a.languages[e]);for(var r in n)t[r]=n[r];return t},insertBefore:function(e,n,t,r){var i=(r=r||a.languages)[e],l={};for(var o in i)if(i.hasOwnProperty(o)){if(o==n)for(var s in t)t.hasOwnProperty(s)&&(l[s]=t[s]);t.hasOwnProperty(o)||(l[o]=i[o])}var u=r[e];return r[e]=l,a.languages.DFS(a.languages,(function(n,t){t===u&&n!=e&&(this[n]=l)})),l},DFS:function e(n,t,r,i){i=i||{};var l=a.util.objId;for(var o in n)if(n.hasOwnProperty(o)){t.call(n,o,n[o],r||o);var s=n[o],u=a.util.type(s);"Object"!==u||i[l(s)]?"Array"!==u||i[l(s)]||(i[l(s)]=!0,e(s,t,o,i)):(i[l(s)]=!0,e(s,t,null,i))}}},plugins:{},highlightAll:function(e,n){a.highlightAllUnder(document,e,n)},highlightAllUnder:function(e,n,t){var r={callback:t,container:e,selector:'code[class*="language-"], [class*="language-"] code, code[class*="lang-"], [class*="lang-"] code'};a.hooks.run("before-highlightall",r),r.elements=Array.prototype.slice.apply(r.container.querySelectorAll(r.selector)),a.hooks.run("before-all-elements-highlight",r);for(var i,l=0;i=r.elements[l++];)a.highlightElement(i,!0===n,r.callback)},highlightElement:function(n,t,r){var i=a.util.getLanguage(n),l=a.languages[i];a.util.setLanguage(n,i);var o=n.parentElement;o&&"pre"===o.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&a.util.setLanguage(o,i);var s={element:n,language:i,grammar:l,code:n.textContent};function u(e){s.highlightedCode=e,a.hooks.run("before-insert",s),s.element.innerHTML=s.highlightedCode,a.hooks.run("after-highlight",s),a.hooks.run("complete",s),r&&r.call(s.element)}if(a.hooks.run("before-sanity-check",s),(o=s.element.parentElement)&&"pre"===o.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&!o.hasAttribute("tabindex")&&o.setAttribute("tabindex","0"),!s.code)return a.hooks.run("complete",s),void(r&&r.call(s.element));if(a.hooks.run("before-highlight",s),s.grammar)if(t&&e.Worker){var c=new Worker(a.filename);c.onmessage=function(e){u(e.data)},c.postMessage(JSON.stringify({language:s.language,code:s.code,immediateClose:!0}))}else u(a.highlight(s.code,s.grammar,s.language));else u(a.util.encode(s.code))},highlight:function(e,n,t){var r={code:e,grammar:n,language:t};if(a.hooks.run("before-tokenize",r),!r.grammar)throw new Error('The language "'+r.language+'" has no grammar.');return r.tokens=a.tokenize(r.code,r.grammar),a.hooks.run("after-tokenize",r),i.stringify(a.util.encode(r.tokens),r.language)},tokenize:function(e,n){var t=n.rest;if(t){for(var r in t)n[r]=t[r];delete n.rest}var a=new s;return u(a,a.head,e),o(e,a,n,a.head,0),function(e){for(var n=[],t=e.head.next;t!==e.tail;)n.push(t.value),t=t.next;return n}(a)},hooks:{all:{},add:function(e,n){var t=a.hooks.all;t[e]=t[e]||[],t[e].push(n)},run:function(e,n){var t=a.hooks.all[e];if(t&&t.length)for(var r,i=0;r=t[i++];)r(n)}},Token:i};function i(e,n,t,r){this.type=e,this.content=n,this.alias=t,this.length=0|(r||"").length}function l(e,n,t,r){e.lastIndex=n;var a=e.exec(t);if(a&&r&&a[1]){var i=a[1].length;a.index+=i,a[0]=a[0].slice(i)}return a}function o(e,n,t,r,s,g){for(var f in t)if(t.hasOwnProperty(f)&&t[f]){var h=t[f];h=Array.isArray(h)?h:[h];for(var d=0;d<h.length;++d){if(g&&g.cause==f+","+d)return;var v=h[d],p=v.inside,m=!!v.lookbehind,y=!!v.greedy,k=v.alias;if(y&&!v.pattern.global){var x=v.pattern.toString().match(/[imsuy]*$/)[0];v.pattern=RegExp(v.pattern.source,x+"g")}for(var b=v.pattern||v,w=r.next,A=s;w!==n.tail&&!(g&&A>=g.reach);A+=w.value.length,w=w.next){var E=w.value;if(n.length>e.length)return;if(!(E instanceof i)){var P,L=1;if(y){if(!(P=l(b,A,e,m))||P.index>=e.length)break;var S=P.index,O=P.index+P[0].length,j=A;for(j+=w.value.length;S>=j;)j+=(w=w.next).value.length;if(A=j-=w.value.length,w.value instanceof i)continue;for(var C=w;C!==n.tail&&(j<O||"string"==typeof C.value);C=C.next)L++,j+=C.value.length;L--,E=e.slice(A,j),P.index-=A}else if(!(P=l(b,0,E,m)))continue;S=P.index;var N=P[0],_=E.slice(0,S),M=E.slice(S+N.length),W=A+E.length;g&&W>g.reach&&(g.reach=W);var z=w.prev;if(_&&(z=u(n,z,_),A+=_.length),c(n,z,L),w=u(n,z,new i(f,p?a.tokenize(N,p):N,k,N)),M&&u(n,w,M),L>1){var I={cause:f+","+d,reach:W};o(e,n,t,w.prev,A,I),g&&I.reach>g.reach&&(g.reach=I.reach)}}}}}}function s(){var e={value:null,prev:null,next:null},n={value:null,prev:e,next:null};e.next=n,this.head=e,this.tail=n,this.length=0}function u(e,n,t){var r=n.next,a={value:t,prev:n,next:r};return n.next=a,r.prev=a,e.length++,a}function c(e,n,t){for(var r=n.next,a=0;a<t&&r!==e.tail;a++)r=r.next;n.next=r,r.prev=n,e.length-=a}if(e.Prism=a,i.stringify=function e(n,t){if("string"==typeof n)return n;if(Array.isArray(n)){var r="";return n.forEach((function(n){r+=e(n,t)})),r}var i={type:n.type,content:e(n.content,t),tag:"span",classes:["token",n.type],attributes:{},language:t},l=n.alias;l&&(Array.isArray(l)?Array.prototype.push.apply(i.classes,l):i.classes.push(l)),a.hooks.run("wrap",i);var o="";for(var s in i.attributes)o+=" "+s+'="'+(i.attributes[s]||"").replace(/"/g,"&quot;")+'"';return"<"+i.tag+' class="'+i.classes.join(" ")+'"'+o+">"+i.content+"</"+i.tag+">"},!e.document)return e.addEventListener?(a.disableWorkerMessageHandler||e.addEventListener("message",(function(n){var t=JSON.parse(n.data),r=t.language,i=t.code,l=t.immediateClose;e.postMessage(a.highlight(i,a.languages[r],r)),l&&e.close()}),!1),a):a;var g=a.util.currentScript();function f(){a.manual||a.highlightAll()}if(g&&(a.filename=g.src,g.hasAttribute("data-manual")&&(a.manual=!0)),!a.manual){var h=document.readyState;"loading"===h||"interactive"===h&&g&&g.defer?document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f):window.requestAnimationFrame?window.requestAnimationFrame(f):window.setTimeout(f,16)}return a}(_self);"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=Prism),"undefined"!=typeof global&&(global.Prism=Prism);

//toolbar plugin
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document){var r=[],i={},n=function(){};Prism.plugins.toolbar={};var t=Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton=function(t,n){var e;e="function"==typeof n?n:function(t){var e;return"function"==typeof n.onClick?((e=document.createElement("button")).type="button",e.addEventListener("click",function(){n.onClick.call(this,t)})):"string"==typeof n.url?(e=document.createElement("a")).href=n.url:e=document.createElement("span"),e.textContent=n.text,e},t in i?console.warn('There is a button with the key "'+t+'" registered already.'):r.push(i[t]=e)},e=Prism.plugins.toolbar.hook=function(a){var t=a.element.parentNode;if(t&&/pre/i.test(t.nodeName)&&!t.parentNode.classList.contains("code-toolbar")){var e=document.createElement("div");e.classList.add("code-toolbar"),t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t),e.appendChild(t);var o=document.createElement("div");o.classList.add("toolbar"),document.body.hasAttribute("data-toolbar-order")&&(r=document.body.getAttribute("data-toolbar-order").split(",").map(function(t){return i[t]||n})),r.forEach(function(t){var e=t(a);if(e){var n=document.createElement("div");n.classList.add("toolbar-item"),n.appendChild(e),o.appendChild(n)}}),e.appendChild(o)}};t("label",function(t){var e=t.element.parentNode;if(e&&/pre/i.test(e.nodeName)&&e.hasAttribute("data-label")){var n,a,o=e.getAttribute("data-label");try{a=document.querySelector("template#"+o)}catch(t){}return a?n=a.content:(e.hasAttribute("data-url")?(n=document.createElement("a")).href=e.getAttribute("data-url"):n=document.createElement("span"),n.textContent=o),n}}),Prism.hooks.add("complete",e)}}();
//autoloader plugin
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document&&document.createElement){var i={javascript:"clike",actionscript:"javascript",arduino:"cpp",aspnet:["markup","csharp"],bison:"c",c:"clike",csharp:"clike",cpp:"c",coffeescript:"javascript",crystal:"ruby","css-extras":"css",d:"clike",dart:"clike",django:"markup-templating",ejs:["javascript","markup-templating"],erb:["ruby","markup-templating"],fsharp:"clike",flow:"javascript",glsl:"clike",gml:"clike",go:"clike",groovy:"clike",haml:"ruby",handlebars:"markup-templating",haxe:"clike",java:"clike",javadoc:["markup","java","javadoclike"],jolie:"clike",jsdoc:["javascript","javadoclike"],"js-extras":"javascript",jsonp:"json",json5:"json",kotlin:"clike",less:"css",markdown:"markup","markup-templating":"markup",n4js:"javascript",nginx:"clike",objectivec:"c",opencl:"cpp",parser:"markup",php:["clike","markup-templating"],phpdoc:["php","javadoclike"],"php-extras":"php",plsql:"sql",processing:"clike",protobuf:"clike",pug:["markup","javascript"],qore:"clike",jsx:["markup","javascript"],tsx:["jsx","typescript"],reason:"clike",ruby:"clike",sass:"css",scss:"css",scala:"java",smarty:"markup-templating",soy:"markup-templating",swift:"clike",tap:"yaml",textile:"markup",tt2:["clike","markup-templating"],twig:"markup",typescript:"javascript","t4-cs":["t4-templating","csharp"],"t4-vb":["t4-templating","visual-basic"],vala:"clike",vbnet:"basic",velocity:"markup",wiki:"markup",xeora:"markup",xquery:"markup"},l={html:"markup",xml:"markup",svg:"markup",mathml:"markup",js:"javascript",adoc:"asciidoc",shell:"bash",rbnf:"bnf",dotnet:"csharp",coffee:"coffeescript",jinja2:"django",dockerfile:"docker",gamemakerlanguage:"gml",hs:"haskell",emacs:"lisp",elisp:"lisp","emacs-lisp":"lisp",md:"markdown",n4jsd:"n4js",objectpascal:"pascal",py:"python",rb:"ruby",ts:"typescript",t4:"t4-cs",vb:"visual-basic",xeoracube:"xeora",yml:"yaml"},n={},a=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),e="components/";if((a=a[a.length-1]).hasAttribute("data-autoloader-path")){var c=a.getAttribute("data-autoloader-path").trim();0<c.length&&!/^[a-z]+:\/\//i.test(a.src)&&(e=c.replace(/\/?$/,"/"))}else/[\w-]+\.js$/.test(a.src)&&(e=a.src.replace(/[\w-]+\.js$/,"components/"));var p=Prism.plugins.autoloader={languages_path:e,use_minified:!0},o=function(a,e,c){"string"==typeof a&&(a=[a]);var s=0,t=a.length,r=function(){s<t?u(a[s],function(){s++,r()},function(){c&&c(a[s])}):s===t&&e&&e(a)};r()},u=function(e,c,s){var t=0<=e.indexOf("!");e=e.replace("!","");var a=function(){var a=n[e];if(a||(a=n[e]={}),c&&(a.success_callbacks||(a.success_callbacks=[]),a.success_callbacks.push(c)),s&&(a.error_callbacks||(a.error_callbacks=[]),a.error_callbacks.push(s)),!t&&Prism.languages[e])m(e);else if(!t&&a.error)k(e);else if(t||!a.loading){a.loading=!0,function(a,e,c){var s=document.createElement("script");s.src=a,s.async=!0,s.onload=function(){document.body.removeChild(s),e&&e()},s.onerror=function(){document.body.removeChild(s),c&&c()},document.body.appendChild(s)}(function(a){return p.languages_path+"prism-"+a+(p.use_minified?".min":"")+".js"}(e),function(){a.loading=!1,m(e)},function(){a.loading=!1,a.error=!0,k(e)})}},r=i[e=l[e]||e];r&&r.length?o(r,a):a()},m=function(e){n[e]&&n[e].success_callbacks&&n[e].success_callbacks.length&&n[e].success_callbacks.forEach(function(a){a(e)})},k=function(e){n[e]&&n[e].error_callbacks&&n[e].error_callbacks.length&&n[e].error_callbacks.forEach(function(a){a(e)})};Prism.hooks.add("complete",function(a){a.element&&a.language&&!a.grammar&&"none"!==a.language&&function(a,e){a in l&&(a=l[a]);var c=n[a];c||(c=n[a]={});var s=e.getAttribute("data-dependencies");!s&&e.parentNode&&"pre"===e.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()&&(s=e.parentNode.getAttribute("data-dependencies")),s=s?s.split(/\s*,\s*/g):[],o(s,function(){u(a,function(){Prism.highlightElement(e)})})}(a.language,a.element)})}}();
//show language plugin
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document)if(Prism.plugins.toolbar){var r={html:"HTML",xml:"XML",svg:"SVG",mathml:"MathML",css:"CSS",clike:"C-like",js:"JavaScript",abap:"ABAP",abnf:"Augmented Backus–Naur form",apacheconf:"Apache Configuration",apl:"APL",arff:"ARFF",asciidoc:"AsciiDoc",adoc:"AsciiDoc",asm6502:"6502 Assembly",aspnet:"ASP.NET (C#)",autohotkey:"AutoHotkey",autoit:"AutoIt",shell:"Bash",basic:"BASIC",bnf:"Backus–Naur form",rbnf:"Routing Backus–Naur form",csharp:"C#",dotnet:"C#",cpp:"C++",cil:"CIL",coffee:"CoffeeScript",cmake:"CMake",csp:"Content-Security-Policy","css-extras":"CSS Extras",django:"Django/Jinja2",jinja2:"Django/Jinja2",dockerfile:"Docker",ebnf:"Extended Backus–Naur form",ejs:"EJS",erb:"ERB",fsharp:"F#",gcode:"G-code",gedcom:"GEDCOM",glsl:"GLSL",gml:"GameMaker Language",gamemakerlanguage:"GameMaker Language",graphql:"GraphQL",hs:"Haskell",hcl:"HCL",http:"HTTP",hpkp:"HTTP Public-Key-Pins",hsts:"HTTP Strict-Transport-Security",ichigojam:"IchigoJam",inform7:"Inform 7",javadoc:"JavaDoc",javadoclike:"JavaDoc-like",javastacktrace:"Java stack trace",jsdoc:"JSDoc","js-extras":"JS Extras",json:"JSON",jsonp:"JSONP",json5:"JSON5",latex:"LaTeX",emacs:"Lisp",elisp:"Lisp","emacs-lisp":"Lisp",lolcode:"LOLCODE",md:"Markdown","markup-templating":"Markup templating",matlab:"MATLAB",mel:"MEL",n1ql:"N1QL",n4js:"N4JS",n4jsd:"N4JS","nand2tetris-hdl":"Nand To Tetris HDL",nasm:"NASM",nginx:"nginx",nsis:"NSIS",objectivec:"Objective-C",ocaml:"OCaml",opencl:"OpenCL",parigp:"PARI/GP",objectpascal:"Object Pascal",php:"PHP",phpdoc:"PHPDoc","php-extras":"PHP Extras",plsql:"PL/SQL",powershell:"PowerShell",properties:".properties",protobuf:"Protocol Buffers",py:"Python",q:"Q (kdb+ database)",jsx:"React JSX",tsx:"React TSX",renpy:"Ren'py",rest:"reST (reStructuredText)",rb:"Ruby",sas:"SAS",sass:"Sass (Sass)",scss:"Sass (Scss)",sql:"SQL",soy:"Soy (Closure Template)",tap:"TAP",toml:"TOML",tt2:"Template Toolkit 2",ts:"TypeScript","t4-cs":"T4 Text Templates (C#)",t4:"T4 Text Templates (C#)","t4-vb":"T4 Text Templates (VB)","t4-templating":"T4 templating",vbnet:"VB.Net",vhdl:"VHDL",vim:"vim","visual-basic":"Visual Basic",vb:"Visual Basic",wasm:"WebAssembly",wiki:"Wiki markup",xeoracube:"XeoraCube",xojo:"Xojo (REALbasic)",xquery:"XQuery",yaml:"YAML",yml:"YAML"};Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton("show-language",function(e){var a=e.element.parentNode;if(a&&/pre/i.test(a.nodeName)){var s,t=a.getAttribute("data-language")||r[e.language]||((s=e.language)?(s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+s.substring(1)).replace(/s(?=cript)/,"S"):s);if(t){var o=document.createElement("span");return o.textContent=t,o}}})}else console.warn("Show Languages plugin loaded before Toolbar plugin.")}();
//copy clipboard plugin
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document)if(Prism.plugins.toolbar){var r=window.ClipboardJS||void 0;r||"function"!=typeof require||(r=require("clipboard"));var i=[];if(!r){var o=document.createElement("script"),e=document.querySelector("head");o.onload=function(){if(r=window.ClipboardJS)for(;i.length;)i.pop()()},o.src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js",e.appendChild(o)}Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton("copy-to-clipboard",function(e){var t=document.createElement("a");return t.textContent="Copy",r?o():i.push(o),t;function o(){var o=new r(t,{text:function(){return e.code}});o.on("success",function(){t.textContent="Copied!",n()}),o.on("error",function(){t.textContent="Press Ctrl+C to copy",n()})}function n(){setTimeout(function(){t.textContent="Copy"},5e3)}})}else console.warn("Copy to Clipboard plugin loaded before Toolbar plugin.")}();
//line numbers plugin
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document){var l="line-numbers",c=/\n(?!$)/g,m=function(e){var t=a(e)["white-space"];if("pre-wrap"===t||"pre-line"===t){var n=e.querySelector("code"),r=e.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows"),s=e.querySelector(".line-numbers-sizer"),i=n.textContent.split(c);s||((s=document.createElement("span")).className="line-numbers-sizer",n.appendChild(s)),s.style.display="block",i.forEach(function(e,t){s.textContent=e||"\n";var n=s.getBoundingClientRect().height;r.children[t].style.height=n+"px"}),s.textContent="",s.style.display="none"}},a=function(e){return e?window.getComputedStyle?getComputedStyle(e):e.currentStyle||null:null};window.addEventListener("resize",function(){Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("pre."+l),m)}),Prism.hooks.add("complete",function(e){if(e.code){var t=e.element,n=t.parentNode;if(n&&/pre/i.test(n.nodeName)&&!t.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows")){for(var r=!1,s=/(?:^|\s)line-numbers(?:\s|$)/,i=t;i;i=i.parentNode)if(s.test(i.className)){r=!0;break}if(r){t.className=t.className.replace(s," "),s.test(n.className)||(n.className+=" line-numbers");var l,a=e.code.match(c),o=a?a.length+1:1,u=new Array(o+1).join("<span></span>");(l=document.createElement("span")).setAttribute("aria-hidden","true"),l.className="line-numbers-rows",l.innerHTML=u,n.hasAttribute("data-start")&&(n.style.counterReset="linenumber "+(parseInt(n.getAttribute("data-start"),10)-1)),e.element.appendChild(l),m(n),Prism.hooks.run("line-numbers",e)}}}}),Prism.hooks.add("line-numbers",function(e){e.plugins=e.plugins||{},e.plugins.lineNumbers=!0}),Prism.plugins.lineNumbers={getLine:function(e,t){if("PRE"===e.tagName&&e.classList.contains(l)){var n=e.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows"),r=parseInt(e.getAttribute("data-start"),10)||1,s=r+(n.children.length-1);t<r&&(t=r),s<t&&(t=s);var i=t-r;return n.children[i]}}}}}();

//set rendering to manual so we can set language to markup for mobile devices first
window.Prism = window.Prism || {};
Prism.manual = true;
    
window.onload = function(){

    var isMobile = false; //initiate as false   
    // device detection
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
        isMobile = true;
    }
        
    if (isMobile) {     
        document.querySelectorAll('code').forEach((input) => {          
            //set language to 'markup' on mobiles - faster rendering        
            for (let i = input.classList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                const className = input.classList[i];
                if (className.startsWith('language-')) {
                    input.classList.remove(className);
                }
            }               
        });
    }
    //highlight code    
    Prism.highlightAll();   
}
```